# Geometric recurrence, prove $g(k)=3g(k-1)-2g(k-2) is g(n)=2^n+1$

Tags: recurrence-relations

Geometric recurrence, prove g<sub>k</sub> = 3g<sub>(k-1)</sub> - 2g<sub>(k-2)</sub> is g<sub>n</sub> = 2<sup>n</sup>+1   using iteration.

g1 = 3, g2 = 5

So,

g<sub>3</sub> = 3g<sub>(2)</sub> - 2g<sub>(1)</sub> = 3(5) - 2(3) = 9  <---- *which is 2<sup>3</sup>+1 = 8+1 = 9

I'm unsure how to prove this?

As k as an exponent not a multiplication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$g_k - g_{k-1} = 2(g_{k-1} - g_{k-2}) = 2^2(g_{k-2} - g_{k-3}) = 2^{k-2}(g_2 - g_1) = 2^{k-2}(5 - 3) = 2^{k-1}$.

Now let $k$ goes from $1$ to $n$:

$g_2 - g_1 = 2$

$g_3 - g_2 = 4$

....

$g_n - g_{n-1} = 2^{n-1}$.

Add these up telescopingly:

$g_n - g_1 = 2 + 4 + ... + 2^{n-1} = 2^n - 2$.

So: $g_n = 2^n - 2 + g_1 = 2^n - 2 + 3 = 2^n + 1$.